# Using an offset variable to keep track of the next item in a Rust array

Tags: comparative-review, rust, iteration, reference

I am using an `offset` variable to track the iteration position, and modifying / returning it. Is the below considered bad practice in Rust? I ask this because I don't see dereferencing very often in code I have seen.

```
fn get_next_u16(input: &[u8], offset: &mut usize) -> u16 {
    let next = ((input[*offset+1] as u16) << 8) +
                (input[*offset]   as u16);
    *offset += 2;
    next
}

fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut offset = 0;
    let first_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
    let second_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
    println!("first: {}", first_u16);
    println!("second: {}", second_u16);
}
```

The other way I think of doing this is to reassign to the offset variable like:

```
fn get_next_u16(input: &[u8], offset: usize) -> (usize, u16) {
   (offset+2, ((input[offset+1] as u16) << 8) +
               (input[offset]   as u16))
}

fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let offset = 0;
    let (offset, first_u16) = get_next_u16(&input, offset);
    let (offset, second_u16) = get_next_u16(&input, offset);
    println!("first: {}", first_u16);
    println!("second: {}", second_u16);
}
```

This looks cleaner but now you have to reassign to offset all the time.

Perhaps there is another way to do this also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Comparing your variants

Your first variant is a **C-style** variant. In C, we only have one return value, not multiple, so poin­ters are the only way to pass more than a single piece of information to the user. Un­fort­u­na­tely, those pointers sometimes get used in a wrong way, which isn't that easy with Rust. Still the fol­lowing code is somewhat repetitive, isn't it?

```
let first_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
let second_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
let third_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
let fourth_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
....
let one_hundred_u16 = get_next_u16(&input, &mut offset);
```

`input` and `offset` are tightly coupled, which shows that there is something amiss. A **struct**­ured way to handle both at the same time would be great. Or we could search some **closure** somewhere else.

The latter variant clearly shows the user that there is more information to work with: The `usize` shouldn't get ignored! After all, it's part of the output. But alas, that's still error prone, since we now can accidentally use the same `offset` twice:

```
let (offset2,  first_u16) = get_next_u16(&input, offset);
let (_      , second_u16) = get_next_u16(&input, offset);     // whoops!
```

That's due to the fact that `usize` implements the `Copy` trait.

## Iterate with iterators

But let's take a step back: you want a safe way to get the next `u16` repeatedly. You want an *iterator*. Slices already provide a [fitting iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) called chunks. Therefore, we can get two `u8`s easily. All we need to do is to map those chunks:

```
fn to_u16(input: &[u8]) -> u16 {
    ((input[1] as u16) << 8) + (input[0] as u16)
}

fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let output: Vec<_> = input.chunks(2).map(to_u16).collect();
    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

Note that this will panic if the `input` doesn't contain an even number of `u8`s. You can use the unstable `chunks_exact` feature or return an `Option<u16>` instead.

## Other remarks

Use `rustfmt` to format your code. That way your code looks similar to the one written by others.

Answer (score 2):

That you really want is to keep a state (the `offset` in this current case). In both the codes you give, `offset` is an "embarrassment": you do not know what to do with it, because it is an implementation detail, not something you want to be bothered by.

The best solution for you is to hide this `offset` in a `struct` and call a method of this `struct`. At each call, the offset is updated, and you get the result. Iterators are exactly for this kind of usage:

```
struct U16Generator<'a> {
    input: &'a [u8],
    offset: usize,
}

impl<'a> U16Generator<'a> {
    fn new(input: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        U16Generator { input, offset: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for U16Generator<'a> {
    type Item = u16;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.input.get(self.offset), self.input.get(self.offset + 1)) {
            (Some(u1), Some(u2)) => {
                self.offset += 2;
                Some(((*u2 as u16) << 8) + *u1 as u16)
            },
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let mut gen = U16Generator::new(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);

    assert_eq!(gen.next(), Some(513));
    assert_eq!(gen.next(), Some(1027));
}
```

One put everything in the `struct` (both the collection and the offset), and at each call of next, one update the `offset` then return the right value.

---

Note that this answer is educational. Obviously, for such a simple use case, this is better to use the Zeta's solution: `input.chunks(2).map(to_u16)`.

Answer (score 2):

A *slice* is a pointer and a length. The pointer doesn't necessarily have to point to the first item of an array! Thus, instead of maintaining an offset, you can update the slice itself.

```
fn get_next_u16(input: &mut &[u8]) -> u16 {
    let next = ((input[1] as u16) << 8) +
                (input[0] as u16);
    *input = &input[2..];
    next
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = &[1u8, 2, 3, 4] as &[_];
    let first_u16 = get_next_u16(&mut input);
    let second_u16 = get_next_u16(&mut input);
    println!("first: {}", first_u16);
    println!("second: {}", second_u16);
}
```

Comment: Even nicer [as an extension method on slices](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=47a28af249c79e9cc4ab585d86b339b5&version=stable), IMO.